# Django reg exp in urls.py

Tags: php, python, regex, django

I want to do a valid string URL to render templates, I want to have URLs like this:

```
url(r'main.php?page=04rent&way=1&filtr=1', render_to_some_tempalte)
url(r'main.php?location=%C1%E0%F0%E2%E8%F5%E0&page=04rent&way=1&filtr=1', render_to_some_tempalte)
```

These URLs, I need to redirect to new templates. These are old URLs from `php` server.

But these strings arent valid, how can I do this to valid URLs string, escape character \ didn't helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes in the URL configuration are not matched with a query string. Leave off the query string (`?` and on) and parse that in a Python view instead.

The `request.GET` mapping gives you access to the query string parameters. Match just `^main.php$` as the route and inspect the query parameters in the view to decide where to redirect to. Use [`redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) from there:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^main.php$', php_redirects, name='php_main')
)

def php_redirects(request):
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    location = request.GET.get('location')
    # look up URL pattern to redirect to.
    targets = {
        '04rent': 'some_url_pattern_name',
    }
    redirect(target[page], location=location)
```

Comment: url(r'^main.php?page=04rent&way=1&filtr=1/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/my_page/') but when i try this in browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/main.php?page=04rent&way=1&filtr=1/ , page not found, why this happens?

Comment: @user3111525: because you cannot include the query string in the path. Everything after `?` is **not** matched here.